# Why does this say undefined offset 2 in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

The `$snippet` variable has the following value:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [user_id] => 2
                [title] => Title
                [detail] => null
                [lang_id] => 19
                [edited] => false
                [last_edited] => 
                [created_date] => 2016-09-25 02:40:03
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [user_id] => 2
                [title] => Some other title
                [detail] => null
                [lang_id] => 19
                [edited] => false
                [last_edited] => 
                [created_date] => 2016-09-25 02:40:03
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [user_id] => 2
                [title] => Huh!
                [detail] => ...
                [lang_id] => 19
                [edited] => false
                [last_edited] => 
                [created_date] => 2016-09-25 03:04:48
            )

    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [user_id] => 2
                [title] => Title
                [detail] => null
                [lang_id] => 19
                [edited] => false
                [last_edited] => 
                [created_date] => 2016-09-25 02:40:03
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [user_id] => 2
                [title] => Some other title
                [detail] => null
                [lang_id] => 19
                [edited] => false
                [last_edited] => 
                [created_date] => 2016-09-25 02:40:03
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [user_id] => 2
                [title] => Huh!
                [detail] => ...
                [lang_id] => 19
                [edited] => false
                [last_edited] => 
                [created_date] => 2016-09-25 03:04:48
            )

    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4
                [user_id] => 2
                [title] => apache
                [detail] => ...
                [lang_id] => 1
                [edited] => false
                [last_edited] => 
                [created_date] => 2016-09-25 03:05:06
            )

    )

)
```

I wanted my result to be something like:

```
Title
Some other title
Huh!
Title
Some other title
Huh!
apache
```

So I tried the following:

```
<?php foreach ($snippet as $key => $value): ?>
    <?= $value[$key]['title'] ?>
    <br />
<?php endforeach ?>
```

But the results were:

```
Title
Some other title

Notice: Undefined offset: 2
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `$snippet[2][2]` does not exist. It is more or less by accident that the others you output exist. You confuse the keys between levels.

Comment: You can use `array_column()` inside the loop and echo the titles.

Comment: @arkascha but $snippet[0][2] exists, But it's not there in the output. I think the array column might work, I'll try it.

Comment: Yes, but your loop tries to access these variables: `$snippet[0][0]['title']`, `$snippet[1][1]['title']`, `$snippet[2][2]['title']`. The last one does _not_ exist.

Comment: `<?=` isn't a feature of Codeigniter but of PHP. It's equivalent to `<?php echo ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
     foreach ($snippet as $value):
        foreach($value as $title):
           echo $title['title']."<br>";
        endforeach;
      endforeach; 
 ?>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Maybe you want to change the naming of `$title` to `$entry` or something similar generic.

Comment: Yep, this is correct. array column might work too but it will be a little messy when i want to display the details as well

Comment: This is good way to solve, but i did it as you need your output.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `array_column()` you can print your title's with the help of `implode()`. This is based on your try, cause you try with one `foreach()`.

```
<?php 
foreach ($snippet as $key => $value):
    echo implode("<br/>", array_column($value[$key], 'title'));
endforeach; 
?>
```

Just try this and let me know is it works or not.

Comment: The loop isn't really needed.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois, Why ?? can you please tell me?

Comment: Because `array_column` can work with multi-dimensional arrays. Just look at the example http://php.net/array_column

Comment: You are right, How much depth searched by this function?

Comment: I don't know. Probably it searches through all sub-arrays. But that's something you have to test.